# Unable to rollout application edition through script

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to roll-out the current version of application using the below command on WAS ND 8.5.

```
<target name="rolloutCurrentVersion">
        <wsadmin
            host="${hostName}" 
            port="${connPort}" 
            user="${userId}" 
            password="${password}"
            conntype="SOAP"
            lang="jacl"
            command="$AdminTask rolloutEdition {-appName ${appName} -edition 4.0 -params '{rolloutStrategy grouped}{resetStrategy soft}{groupSize 1}{drainageInterval 60}'}"
        />
    </target>
```

When this task executes, it give me following message:

```
[wsadmin] WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminTask rolloutEdition {-appName My_App_Cluster -edition 4.0 -params '{rolloutStrategy grouped}{resetStrategy soft}{groupSize 1}{drainageInterval 60}'}"; exception information:
[wsadmin] com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.RequiredParameterNotFoundException: ADMF0002E: Required parameter appName is not found for command rolloutEdition.
```

I have already mentioned the "-appName" parameter in the command. Is there something wrong with the syntax? I used [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwve_adtaskapped.html?lang=en) documentation to make the command.

Comment: Try to invoke it directly via wsadmin for a test, not ant, and see if it makes any difference, Also are you sure that you  set variables correctly as `My_App_Cluster` sounds more like cluster name not application name.

Comment: @Gas The variable is set correctly, it signifies app deployed on cluster. I ran the command directly via wsadmin but it is game me same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change the command to make that work. Instead of passing params in quotes I passed the values in braces. e.g.

**I Passed:**

```
command="$AdminTask rolloutEdition {-appName ${appName} -edition 4.0 -params {{rolloutStrategy grouped}{resetStrategy soft}{groupSize 1}{drainageInterval 60}}}"
```

**Instead of:**

```
command="$AdminTask rolloutEdition {-appName ${appName} -edition 4.0 -params '{rolloutStrategy grouped}{resetStrategy soft}{groupSize 1}{drainageInterval 60}'}"
```